# Realm Swift Package Dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, swift-package-manager

I am getting the error message 'No such module 'RealmSwift' when I added Realm to my project.
I have deleted Derived data, cleaned build folder, restart XCode still error persist.
Please what do I need to do?

Comment: Can you update your question and tell us what steps you took to include Realm? I would suggest using Cocoapds as it's very reliable and super simple.

Comment: Do you have a lot of other errors? I've seen this come up sometimes when I'm refactoring a class and have introduced a lot of bugs, as I clean up the consequences of refactoring and the number of errors decreases, that error just went away.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have added the Realm SDK to your project correctly.
Please refer to this [Realm Documentation for iOS SDK](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/install/) for installation.

Please share the code snippet or screenshot where you are facing the issue for better help.